# How do I create nested properties? C#

Tags: c#, properties

As far as I read, creating nested properties don't seem to be possible in c#.

What I want to do is:

```
Callout callout = new Callout();
callout.Font.Size = 200;
```

This is the code I currently have

```
class Callout
{
     // nested properties
}
```

I know how to create properties, but how do I create a nested property?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```cs
class Callout {
    public Font Font {get;} = new Font();
}
class Font {
    public int Size {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: Is there another way to do that without Font being a class, Stackoverflow highlighted Font like a class.

Comment: Yes, you can use a struct

Comment: @SirRufo just to note... mutable structs are almost never a good idea (I will forgive mutable structs in the case of a: custom iterators, and b: `ref struct`)

Comment: @MarcGravell I know, but the OP asks for another way ;o)

Comment: I misunderstood what was going on the code, but a class works perfectly :) Thanks a lot @MarcGravell

Comment: @SirRufo the code in the question wouldn't work with a mutable struct - you'd be editing a copy out in the nowhere

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Callout {

    public Font Font {get;}
}

public struct Font {
    public Font(int size) {
        Size = size;
    }

    public int Size {get;}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you really don't want to implement a separate class or struct, here's a tricky way to do what you are asking.

Note: Tricky != Recommended

```
class Callout : Callout.IFont
{
    public interface IFont
    {
        int Size { get; set; }
    }
    protected int _fontSize = 0;

    int IFont.Size
    {
        get
        {
            return _fontSize;   
        }
        set
        {
            _fontSize = value;
        }
    }

    public IFont Font => this;
}


var callout = new Callout();
callout.Font.Size = 100;
```

Comment: A class works perfectly for me now. I just misunderstood the code.